# How to open a file from an archive in vba without unzipping the archive

Tags: excel, vba, unzip

I have a serie of archives : C:/archive1.zip, C:/archive2.zip, etc.

I want to extract only one file from each archive.
Each archive has same structure and file can found under :

C:/archive1.zip/folderlevel1/folderlevel2/folderlevel3/Myfile.csv
C:/archive2.zip/folderlevel1/folderlevel2/folderlevel3/Myfile.csv

etc.

How can I read all the file Myfile.csv in vba ?

Thanks!

Comment: See example 2 here: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win002.htm

Answer (score 12):

You can do it as this:

```
'
' UnZip 1 file from a zip file:
'
Function entUnZip1File(ByVal strZipFilename, ByVal strDstDir, _
  ByVal strFilename)
'
  Const glngcCopyHereDisplayProgressBox = 256
'
  Dim intOptions, objShell, objSource, objTarget
'
' Create the required Shell objects
  Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
'
' Create a reference to the files and folders in the ZIP file
  Set objSource = _
    objShell.NameSpace(strZipFilename).Items.item(CStr(strFilename))
'
' Create a reference to the target folder
  Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(strDstDir)
'
  intOptions = glngcCopyHereDisplayProgressBox
'
' UnZIP the files
  objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptions
'
' Release the objects
  Set objSource = Nothing
  Set objTarget = Nothing
  Set objShell = Nothing
'
  entUnZip1File = 1
'
End Function
```

And any where in your macro, call the function to extract the file into C:\temp directory or to any destination folder instead of C:\temp:

```
entUnZip1File "C:\archive1.zip", "C:\temp", "folderlevel1/folderlevel2/folderlevel3/Myfile.csv"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jacouh. It works really well. Actually, it was easier than I thought. I guess I had not understood the power of the Object.Namespace function !