# Crawling through Zip files

Tags: vba, excel, automation, zip

I'm trying to crawl through a certain drive and grab data off of certain .xls files that are buried in sub-directories. The drive is over a TB, and the folders don't all have the same hierarchy, so I'm crawling through all of them. So far, the script works great.

The problem is, there are zipped files in the drive. At least half the files are in zipped format. How can I crawl through these files as well?

Here is the part of my code that crawls through the sub-directories. There is another function "TrailingSlash" which just appends a "\" to the string if it doesn't already have one.  I give credit to the author in my comments.

```
Public Function recursiveDir(colFiles As Collection, strFolder As String, strFileSpec As String, bIncludeSubfolders As Boolean) as Collection

    'From Ammara.com/access_image_faq/recursive_folder_search.html
    'Recursive function to search document tree from specific file extension

    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim colFolders As New Collection
    Dim vFolderName As Variant
    Dim colFiles As New Collection
    Dim counter As Integer

    'Add files in strFolder matching strFileSpec to colFiles
    strFolder = TrailingSlash(strFolder)
    strTemp = Dir(strFolder & strFileSpec)

    On Error Resume Next
    Do While strTemp <> vbNullString
        colFiles.Add (strFolder & strTemp)
        counter = counter + 1
        Debug.Print ("files found: " & counter)
        strTemp = Dir
    Loop

    If bIncludeSubfolders Then
        'Fill colFolders with list of subdirectories of strFolder
        strTemp = Dir(strFolder, vbDirectory)
        Do While strTemp <> vbNullString
            If (strTemp <> ".") And (strTemp <> "..") Then
                If (GetAttr(strFolder & strTemp) And vbDirectory) <> 0 Then
                    colFolders.Add strTemp
                End If
            End If
            strTemp = Dir
        Loop

        'Call recursiveDir for each subfolder in colFolders
        For Each vFolderName In colFolders
            Call recursiveDir(colFiles, strFolder & vFolderName, strFileSpec, True)
        Next vFolderName
    End If

recursiveDir = colFiles

End Function
```

The function adds all the path strings to the collection "colFolders", which I then use to open and extract data from. I'm now thinking there may not be a simple way to return a string path to a file within a zipped folder. There may need to be a separate function that is called when this function encounters a zip, that in turn crawls through the zipped folder and extracts the specific file to a local destination (as long as I don't have to extract the whole folder, we should be good).

I'm kind of lost in what I should do. Googleing around points me towards using shell.Application. I know nothing of shells, is this the path I should take?

Thanks SO - you all are awesome!

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716587/how-to-open-a-file-from-an-archive-in-vba-without-unzipping-the-archive) may help, if you can iterate through `objShell.NameSpace(strZipFilename).Items`

Comment: So the idea is to iterate through the objShell, similar to using the Dir() iteration? I guess I'll have to dig into Application.Shell. How would this work with digging into sub-directories?

Comment: As you trawl each sub-directory, when you find a zip file you can search the items - items in an zip file don't have a directory structure until unzipped.

Comment: Ohh! Good call! So the zip file is completely flat? That makes this much easier.

Comment: Wait.. but that answer you supplied, that example implies a file hierarchy of  "folderlevel1/folderlevel2/folderlevel3/Myfile.csv" no?

Comment: That hierarchy is where the file is extracted to.

Comment: objShell.NameSpace(strZipFilename).Items.item(CStr(strFilename))--Isn't this trying to find strFileName ("folder1/folder2/file.csv") in the strZipFilename ("archive.zip")? If it was just looking for the file sans hierarchy, shouldn't simply "file.csv" be one of the items in the namespace? They extract the file to objTarget - but the folders are in objSource...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead to search through subfolders:

```
Sub SO()

Dim x, i

x = GetFiles("C:\Users\SO\Folder", "*.xls*", True) '// x becomes an array of files found

For Each i In x
   Debug.Print i
Next i

End Sub

'-------------------------------------------------

Function GetFiles(StartPath As String, FileType As String, SubFolders As Boolean) As Variant

StartPath = StartPath & IIf(Right(StartPath, 1) = "\", vbNullString, "\") 'Sanity check

GetFiles = Split(Join(Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR """ & StartPath & FileType & """ " & _
   IIf(SubFolders, "/S", vbNullString) & " /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), ":"), "#"), "#")

End Function
```

But for zip files, there isn't really anything native to windows that will allow you to do this other than the `CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(zipName).Items` method.

I prefer to use 7-zip which is free, open-source and has a great command line utility which means you can access it via VBA too using the `CreateObject("WScript.Shell")` method (like above)

Comment: Hey I tried setting up a loop for the filenames in x. But it doesnt work

Comment: @MaximTeleguz you haven't included the UDF. But firstly, you should ask this as a new question as your issue is syntax, not functionality

Comment: i only posted what i changed in your code. All the rest i used as it was.

Comment: they wont let me post anymore questions.

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't post a question, but the setup on this site is that each question should have its own separate post. This is to ensure that the information in each page is relevant and people searching the web for solutions hit the right page the first time. I can only suggest that when possible you post your question regarding the loop and if it's got a [tag:vba] or [tag:excel] tag then I'll more than likely see it and pick it up.

Comment: Apparently i had too many downvotes when i asked a stupid question a little while ago. 

Can you please help? Im so frustrated and sooo alooone. somebody, anybody? lol