# Copying files from zip folder excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I found this sub routine online and it works fine.

My problem now is the files selected need to be extracted from a zip folder. Not all files in the zip folder need to be extracted just the ones selected in the original routine.

Is it possible to modify this to extract the files selected and copied to the new folder selected in initial routine.

```
Sub copyfiles()
'Updateby Extendoffice
    Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
    Dim xSFileDlg As FileDialog, xDFileDlg As FileDialog
    Dim xSPathStr As Variant, xDPathStr As Variant
    Dim xVal As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the file names:", "KuTools For Excel", ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address, , , , , 8)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set xSFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xSFileDlg.Title = "Please select the original folder:"
    If xSFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    xSPathStr = xSFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
    Set xDFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xDFileDlg.Title = "Please select the destination folder:"
    If xDFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    xDPathStr = xDFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
    For Each xCell In xRg
        xVal = xCell.Value
        If TypeName(xVal) = "String" And xVal <> "" Then
            FileCopy xSPathStr & xVal, xDPathStr & xVal
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds possible to me. What have you tried? What problem did you run into?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716587/how-to-open-a-file-from-an-archive-in-vba-without-unzipping-the-archive