# Open a file from a zip archive in vba without unzipping

Tags: excel, vba, zip

I have a .csv file zipped in an archive, I want to open the .csv file directly in Excel in VBA without unzipping it to a temporary directory. That is, I'd like the behavior of opening the .csv file from the .zip file in File Explorer.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716587/how-to-open-a-file-from-an-archive-in-vba-without-unzipping-the-archive) asks the question but the answer requires saving to a temp directory that I need to manage. I need to manipulate the csv file long after this macro completes so I want an answer that cleans up automatically when I close the .csv file or save it as something else; I'll accept use of a temp directory *if it gets automatically cleaned up*, i.e. the temp extract files get deleted after closing.

Yes, I know that opening the .csv file from within the .zip archive in File Explorer creates a temporary directory under my AppData\Local\Temp directory called "Temp1_<filename>", where <filename> is the name of the .csv file. I'm happy with that since the OS (or is it Explorer?) deletes it automatically after I close the file; this is the behaviour I want to replicate from VBA code.

I tried opening the .csv from the Namespace object:

```
Function OpenFromZip(fileZip As String, nameOpen As String) As Workbook
   Dim oApp As Object, oSrc As Object
   Dim vFileZip As Variant, vNameOpen As Variant
   
   vFileZip = fileZip
   vNameOpen = nameOpen
   Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
   Set oSrc = oApp.Namespace(vFileZip).Items.Item(vNameOpen)
   Set OpenFromZip = Workbooks.Open(oSrc)
   Set oApp = Nothing
   Set oSrc = Nothing
End Function
```

The Workbook.Open fails with Run-time error '1004'
Sorry, we couldn't find . Is it possible it was moved, renamed, or deleted?

`Set OpenFromZip = Workbooks.Open(oSrc.Path)` gave the Excel not found error "Sorry, we couldn't find '<nameOpen>'. Is it possible it was moved renamed or deleted?" before the Run-time error '1004' with the full path name, as does constructing the full pathname without using the Shell object at all.

Can the magic of Explorer be replicated in VBA code?

Comment: Extract the file to your temp folder and open it from there - that should not be a problem?  Pretty sure it needs to be a file *somewhere* before it can be opened in Excel.

Comment: Yes, I don't mind a temp file but I want the auto-delete of the temp file that opening from within the archive in Explorer provides.

Comment: Is that important though?

Comment: I would create a subdirectory in AppData\Local\Temp and when the procedure is finished, remove the whole subdir-tree. When your program aborts for whatever reason, clean the subdirectory before you start unpacking the next time.